# SSL wildcard certificate for multiple subdomains / ip's?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain

I have multiple subdomains running web servers that I was to put SSL onto.

Say they are `linux.mydomain.com`, `windows.mydomain.com` and `mac.mydomain.com`. each is its own vps and has its own IP (and a different OS, but that is by-the-by). The `linux.mydomain.com` server handles the DNS. Can I get a single SSL certificate `*.mydomain.com` to cover running SSL on all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You would need to ensure that all sites shared the same private key - and this represents a small security risk, but its entirely practical to do this.  (Its not dissimilar to having distributed servers all with the same set of domains).

The certificate is bound to a private key, not an IP address, so that is almost irrelevant.

I'm sure you had worked this much out, but the type of cert you want is probably a wildcard cert.  There are some limitations of these (for example you can't get Extended validation).

Comment: I thought as much, but it seemed most answers I found also had mentioned that it was a single IP with subdomains. Thanks for the info!

Comment: The single IP thing may be a single server thing - some registrars have inane artificial restrictions on certs - I know that when I got an EV Cert from Thawte for a client they had this restriction - and it was purely a license thing, there was no technical barrier to running it on multiple machines.